# How to find an item in an object of array

Tags: arrays, swift, maps, swiftui, swift5

I have a list of IDs. Also I have an object that has arrays of datas like the below structure.

```
[
    foods(
        foodId: 345, 
        category: 10, 
        tools: [10], 
        name: "food name 1"
    ),

    foods(
        foodId: 191, 
        category: 4, 
        tools: [2], 
        name: "food name 2"
    ), 
]
```

In my list I have list `[345, 191]`

I want to have a mechanism to access the information of the object when I provide a `foodId`.

I made it work with one inner and one outer loop. But I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it:

```
ForEach(foodDetails, id: \.self){ item in
    ForEach(self.foods.datas){ ex in
        if(ex.foodId == item){
            Text(ex.name)
    }
}
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do simply by getting first element where id match

```
let result = foodDetails.first(where: {$0.foodId == id})

 if let food = result {
        print(food.name ?? "") //if name is optional
        print(food.foodId)
        print(food.category)
    }
```

result you got is that foods? optional struct which have this id

Comment: Thanks it does return whole array indeed. However, if I want to get an element in that array, such as `result.name`, does not seem to work.

Comment: you will access it  `result?.name`

Comment: This is great. I will submit it as answer. Only `result?.name` returns and array like `Optional("Burger")`. Is there anyway to return is as the actual string? like `Burger`? I tried `resutl?.name[0]` but didint work.

Comment: yes .. do optional binding on it ...  i think your name is optional right ?

Comment: All arrays will have a name element so, it should not be optional I guess. But why would it return the value in array as  `("name")`?

Comment: can you share your `foods` struct ?